# Adobe Premiere Pro Extension using ".exe" file

Tags: c++, plugins, scripting, extendscript, adobe-premiere

Currently I'm developing an `extension for Premiere Pro` that should use `.exe` file to make things happen.

The main algorithm is written in `python` and works with actual `video files`: reads them frame by frame, processes the information in pixel level... I'm thinking of making an executable from it and call it from `extendscript` to make things happen...

Is this the right way to go ? Or should I consider other technics like writing a `plugin using the PPro SDK` and call it from extendscript ? Is it possibe to access the actual video-files, read them, get pixel values with SDK ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how good the Premiere SDK is, but the drawback I can see to use the SDK you would have to port everything to C++. If that's less work than creating the Extendscript bridge it would be the way to go.

The PPro Extendscript documentation is notoriously non-existent.

Comment: Thanks @stib ;) I guess I'll go on with python